# Is there a Windows Media Player plugin to send music info to a webpage?

Tags: windows-7, plugins, windows-media-player, http, tracking

I'm looking for a way to track my music playing on my website and am trying to find a way to post the music information, such as all the music file details (i.e. title, album, year, etc), when the song is played to a page on my website for processing. Is there a plugin for this or a way to make a plugin for this easily? Or even an alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Last.fm](http://last.fm) utilizes a service known as 'Scrobbling' which does integrate with Windows Media Player as well as most other common media players. Sign up on their website and follow the instructions to setup Windows Media Player to report what you are listening.

I'm sure that you can pull your last.fm stats via RSS feed to your own site and then regurgitate the results in your own format as well.